# Correct usage of If/else condition in MySQL based on a session variable

Tags: mysql, database

If I set a session variable (eg. @tmp = 0), then a query can be run/ignored depending on whether a condition is met.

```
SET @create_table := IF(@tmp >= 1, 'CREATE TABLE table2 SELECT * FROM table1', 'no');
```

This is usable for a short query like the example above, but not so for more complex queries with multiple statements. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
IF(@tmp >= 1)
DO SOMETHING
ELSE
DO NOTHING
```

Comment: Do not confuse [IF() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if) and [IF statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html). The function can be used as any other function (your 1st code) whereas the statement can be used in stored object only (procedure, function, trigger, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) is as follow.

```sql
IF condition1 THEN
   {...statements to execute when condition1 is TRUE...}

[ ELSEIF condition2 THEN
   {...statements to execute when condition1 is FALSE and condition2 is TRUE...} ]

[ ELSE
   {...statements to execute when both condition1 and condition2 are FALSE...} ]

END IF;
```